# How to eliminate spaces for installation while writing Inno setup file?

Tags: inno-setup

I am creating an installer for my project where I am facing a issue.

The project is not running as expected if it is installed in the directory which contains spaces  e.g: "C:\Program Files (x86)" and it is working fine if it is installed in a directory which doesn't contains spaces e.g: "C:\Python27".

So as per my understanding there is nothing wrong with project side and its all with the .iss code.

So can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue. Since most of the installers are created using Inno setup and they are installed in the program files there will be a way to solve this and which I am not aware of it.

Regards,

Bharathi

Comment: Please alaborate - what is the problem exactly you want to solve? Could you post an example or the error message you get? Does the problem occur during compilation process or during the install process or maybe it occurs after the installation is complete and you try to run the app?

Comment: Besides, the problem is in your application. It's not Inno Setup's deal, that your application cannot run from directory with spaces.

Comment: @RobenN There is no problem with installation. It goes fine without any error. When I run my application by clicking a button, the button is not responding - its behaving like no code has been written to that button.

Comment: @TLama I dont want to avoid the spaces, I want my application to work in all cases. And I even cross checked my application i.e I installed my app in the path "D:\Program Files (x86)" which is working fine but If the same app is installed in the path "C:\Program Files (x86)"  it is not working.

Comment: Well, so then fix your application. I can't see anything related to installer here. What does mean *"when I run my application by clicking a button, the button is not responding"* ? Which button, where ?

Comment: @TLama My application works fine if I install it anywhere else other than these two paths i.e "C:\Program Files (x86)" and "C:\Program Files" I don't think so it is related to spaces. Is there any specific keyword related to Program Files and why is it not working only with these two paths?

Comment: Does your application attempts to write to a folder where it's installed ? Does it run elevated ? If your answers are yes and no, then you most probably doesn't have privileges to do that and your application silently fails to execute. You don't have privileges to write to those folders. They are reserved for system.

Comment: Oh ya, I think your correct. The application is a python script and while executing it will tries to write the .pyc file in the installed folder. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: You should be writing only to folders that are for this purpose. In this case I feel it might be application data folder which is writable for your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with the spaces. My application creates a log file to log the data. Since the  normal user doesn't have rights to create the file in the program files folder the application is not working...  The application should be run as admin to work.

Comment: No. The solution should not be that you run your app elevated. You should never write logs to the application folder. That folder is for application, not for its data. There are Application Data directories where you should write your logs.

Answer (score -1):

Create a symlink using `mklink`.
Create something like this in `[RUN]` section:

```
Filename: {cmd}; Parameters: "/c MKLINK /D {sd}\ProgramPathNoSpaces ""{pf}\Program Path With Spaces"; Flags: RunHidden;
```

Run your application inside the `ProgramPathNoSpaces`, using a shortcut with the "start in" property defined.

Hope this help you, but everyone is right. The problem is in the application, this is only a workaround.

Comment: And the award for "most hackiest method of the year" goes to...
In short, don't do this, it's a hack to work around a bug in the application and polutes the user's system. Also note that `{pf}` may not be on the same drive as {sd} causing the hardlink to fail.

Comment: I don't comment if you should fix the application or not. Sometimes you're not the owner, but I avoid discuss this with you here and everywhere. But you are wrong. The hardlink work. {pf} don't need to be in the same drive as {sd}, and if you're in good faith, you know is true.

Comment: NTFS hard links require the folders to be on the same partition. I stand be exactly what I said.

Comment: As `mklink /d` defaults to a symlink, I've edited your question to suit.